# crash in cvBlobsLib VS2008

Tags: opencv

I am using cvBlobsLib library for a blob detection work, however, i am facing a crash in the program in the code.
My code crashes at this point:

```
CBlobResult blobs;
blobs = CBlobResult(imageSkinPixels, NULL, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`imageSkinPixels` must be a single-channel image: in other words, you need to convert your RGB image to GRAY before passing it to `CBlobResult()`.

Also, we don't know what is the type of `imageSkinPixels`, but it should be a pointer to `IplImage`.

That's all I can say with the code you shared. If this doesn't fix the problem you'll need to share more code.